# interrupting nested setInterval when function is called again

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to execute a function only if the timer limit hits 750ms.

Use case: enter a few characters in rapid succession such that the delay between any successive input is <750ms. if the delay between inputs is >750ms, execute a function and send it the data from the input.

Ideal console output after inputting 5 characters in rapid succession:

```
5 --- SUBMIT INPUT
1 -- BREAK
```

Current output:

```
5 --- SUBMIT INPUT
5 -- BREAK
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uuv4vkst/2/

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but approached the algorithm in a different way. Here's my solution - https://jsfiddle.net/Lfammf6v/ . Just so you can see clearly I've put the timeout at 2 seconds. I will explain what is wrong with your code and my algorithm approach in a more elaborate answer shortly, but the code is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls should help

Comment: @AbhilashSingh Nice thanks. However sometimes right after you input something, break fires immediately, not every time though.

Comment: @eveo, I suspected that is what you needed. Here you go with your new requirements, just an extra case that needed to be addressed. https://jsfiddle.net/tLmbatuL/

Comment: [rxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) provides that out-of-the-box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetInterval inside a Closure, inside a For loop, creates too many intervals, won't stop running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212465/setinterval-inside-a-closure-inside-a-for-loop-creates-too-many-intervals-won)